# Inductive definition of concatenation of strings

Tags: logic, induction

May someone help me understand the following inductive definition of *concatenation of strings*:

We will define $\alpha\cdot\beta$ by induction on $|\beta|.$

- If $|\beta|=0\Rightarrow \beta=\epsilon,$ so then $\alpha\cdot\beta=\alpha\cdot\epsilon=\alpha$
- If $|\beta|=n+1,$ then $\beta=\gamma b,|\gamma|=n.$ Then $\alpha\cdot\beta=(\alpha\cdot\gamma)b$.

I understand the basis of the induction. At least I think I do.

Perhaps I don't understand how inductive definitions work. When $\beta$ is the empty word, then it's obvious that when we concatenate it with $\alpha$, we'll get $\alpha$ again. But then I don't understand what happens next and why we take the length of $\beta$ to be $n+1$. What's the idea? What's the inductive step when using induction to define a new object (how do we use it)?

Thanks!

Comment: Thinking about some examples may help you understand. For example, let $\alpha = \mathrm{abc}$ and $\beta = \mathrm{def}$. Then, by the inductive definition, we can say that $\alpha \cdot \beta = \left( \alpha \cdot \gamma \right) \mathrm f = \left( \left( \alpha \cdot \delta \right) \mathrm e \right) \mathrm f = \left( \left( \left( \alpha \cdot \epsilon \right) \mathrm d \right) \mathrm e \right) \mathrm f =  \left( \left( \left( \alpha \right) \mathrm d \right) \mathrm e \right) \mathrm f = \mathrm{abcdef}$, where $\gamma = \mathrm{de}$ and $\delta = \mathrm d$.

Answer (score 0):

> May someone help me understand the following inductive definition of concatenation of strings

You would have an *inductive definition* of "string", which typically has two constructors, one for the "empty" string, and one for the "compound" string with one head character followed by the rest of the string.  (In fact, here a "string" isn't but a "list of characters".)

Then you would have a *recursive definition* of "concatenation of strings" by cases on the structure of one of the operands, not on its length: in your example, we consider $\beta$, with one case for $\beta$ empty, the other for $\beta$ a compound string.

Of course, for an appropriate definition of "size of a string", if $|\beta| = 0$, one can derive $\beta = \operatorname {empty}$, and, if $|\beta| \neq 0$, one can derive $\beta = h :: \gamma$ for some character $h$ and string $\gamma$, but that is an extra preliminary step that is not needed to reason inductively (on inductive strings as well as in general).

> What's the inductive step when using induction to define a new object (how do we use it)?

The "inductive step" is a step in *proof by induction*, so it is rather relevant in proving theorems about inductive structures.

More could be said but it gets quickly very technical: I'd rather invite you to consider what I have said above while (re)reading introductory articles and material, especially about "mathematical induction".